# Query on many-to-many relationship Users -> Classes

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, many-to-many, backend

I have two entities, Users and Classes, with a many to many relationship. I'm working with .Net Core, and I set up the relationship following this blog post [HERE](https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2017/09/25/many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-core-2-0-part-3-hiding-as-icollection/) (up to part 3). The database works, and I'm able to add classes and fill the join table, but I don't know how to retrieve all the classes the user is enrolled in, or the other way around all the users that are enrolled in a specific class.

I need that to solve the case in which the user is already signed into a class and I don't have to add a new entry to the join table (which would still throw an error).

User.cs

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    // Making the classes a JoinCollectionFacade allows us to perform actions like adding a class
    public User()
        => Classes = new JoinCollectionFacade<Class, UserClass>(
            UserClass,
            uc => uc.Class,
            c => new UserClass { User = this, Class = c });

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    //public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Membership { get; set; }

    private ICollection<UserClass> UserClass { get; } = new List<UserClass>();

    // This element does not need to be mapped. It's used for easier reference
    // to the Users enrolled in the class
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Class> Classes { get; }
}
```

Class.cs

```
public class Class
{

    // Making the classes a JoinCollectionFacade allows us to perform actions like adding a class
    public Class()
        => Users = new JoinCollectionFacade<User, UserClass>(
            UserClass,
            uc => uc.User,
            u => new Models.UserClass { User = u, Class = this });

    public Class(Instructor i, string d)
    {
        Instructor = i;
        Description = d;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Instructor Instructor { get; set; } // Made virtual so we can take advantage of certain Entity Framework such as lazy loading (from Microsoft docs)
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    private ICollection<UserClass> UserClass { get; } = new List<UserClass>();

    // This element does not need to be mapped. It's used for easier reference
    // to the Users enrolled in the class
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; }
}
```

UserClass.cs

```
public class UserClass
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: At the very least, you should post those 2 classes. The User class should have a collection of Class objects, so if you query for a particular user and include the class list, you get what you need. I can only assume the entities are mapped like this based on your description.

Comment: I edited the question and included my classes.

Comment: Try removing those `NotMapped` attributes and you should be able to include those in your query.

Comment: That is not solving the problem for me. Would you mind giving me an example of the query that I'm looking for?

Comment: Your problem is that you followed some blog's approach that doesn't allow you to do includes, which is exactly the solution to your problem. You can see a clear example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) down at the bottom.

Comment: With what you have, you have to do a join to UserClass to get either users for a classId,or classes for a userId, as you mention that this join table is properly populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by

- making the instances of UserClass public in both User.cs and Class.cs
- using this kind of query below to retrieve all the users enrolled in a specific class

```
var usersInClass = _context.Users
                      .Include(i => i.UserClass).ThenInclude(i => i.Class)
                      .Where(x => x.UserClass.Select(pc => pc.Class).Any(c => c.Id == id))
                      .ToList();
```